# Focus is not set back to ScrollViewer instead of specific child element

Tags: uwp

I have custom control from GridView. Inside the grid view, have loaded a editor control. I forced to set the focus to CustomGridView  like below in OnPointerReleasedEVent.

```
customGridView.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic)
```

But the focus is set back to ScrollViewer instead of CustomizedGridView.

Why this is not set to CustomGridView?

Comment: Do you have more code? Which `ScrollViewer` are you talking about?

Comment: Focus is set back to Window's ScrollViewer . i'm not talking about the scrollviewer which is present in my sample

Comment: Might it be that the framework sets the focus after you? Have you tried setting a delay of something like 50-100 ms and see if it works then? It's hacky, but it'll test if the framework is delayed in setting focus